# Replacing numpy array with max value

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array,

```
a = np.array([[0,9,8],[5,6,4]])
```

how to replace the each array in axis 1 with the max value of its array?

excepting output- `a = np.array([9,6])` where 9 is the max value in [0,9,8] and 6 is the max value in [5,6,4]

thanks

Comment: `a.max(axis=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
np.max(a, axis=1)
```

[Link to documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html)

Answer (score 0):

another implementation you can do this

```
np.array([max(i) for i in a])
```