# Replacing Numpy Array - Python

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]) #a.shape = (3,3)
```

How to replace each array in `a` with its max value?

Excepted output - `a = np.array([1, 2, 5]) #a.shape = (3,1)`

Thanks

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *max value*? I think you need to clarify how that output is expected.

Comment: If there is a typo and you expect `[1, 3, 5]` instead, that's the exact same question you asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68270289/replacing-numpy-array-with-max-value)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing numpy array with max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68270289/replacing-numpy-array-with-max-value)

Comment: @RandomGuy, thanks for writing, I found the answer, and also the link helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
a = np.amax(a, axis=1)
```

see the documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html)